# android studio gradle build Error Error:Execution failed for task ':packageAllDevDebugClassesForMultiDex'. >

Tags: android, gradle

I have been using Android Studios from eclipe becuse Multidex 65000 compile Error!!!!

i did sync project gradle in android studio from eclipse project

i have problem compile Error in android studio

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':packageAllDevDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>
> > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14.class

--build.gradle--

```
     buildscript {

        repositories {

            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

    dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }

    android 
    {
        compileSdkVersion 18
        buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

        defaultConfig{
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        }

        productFlavors {
            dev {
                minSdkVersion 18
            }
            prod {
                minSdkVersion 18
            }
        }

}
```

why problem occurring 
i want this problem solve
help me error sovle please

Comment: Which libraries do you use in libs folder?

Comment: I am getting this same error. All I did was add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` to the dependencies section in my gradle file.